# Importing and Exporting Data using MASS package

Tags: r

[here is a link to a picture of my file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImfN9.png) 
I am trying to plot data from a package and can't quite get it. This is what I have so far.

```
#Importing and Exporting Data

  #Get the demo data that comes with the "MASS" package

getwd()
setwd("~/")
setwd("College/2021-2022/Fall 2021/Programming for Biologists BIOM 419/R Project 1/")

install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)
data()

#Plot body weight (kg) vs brain weight (g) and label the axes and add a title
plot(mammals$body, mammals$brain, col="RED", pch=15, cex=1,
     xlab="Body Weight", ylab="Brain Weight", 
     main="Plot of Brain Wt. as a Function of Body Wt.")
mammals1<-mammals[order(mammals$body),]
mammals1$logbody<-log(mammals1$body)
mammals1$logbrain<-log(mammals1$brain)
```

For reference, my professor's next instructions are to

make a scatterplot of the log transformed body and brain weights

Read in `Tick_2017_map.csv` (which is located in a sub folder under "data" in College/2021-2022/Fall 2021/Programming for Biologists BIOM 419/R Project 1/"

These are the errors I am getting:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
> 'Tick_2017_map.txt': No such file or directory
>
> > str(map.2) Error in str(map.2) : object 'map.2' not found
> >
> > summary(map.2$species) Error in summary(map.2$species) : object 'map.2' not found
> > map.s <- map.2[map.2$specoes == "sanguineus", c(1:8)] Error: object 'map.2' not found
> > table(map.s$species) Error in table(map.s$species) : object 'map.s' not found
> > write.csv(map.s, file = "Sangeineus.txt") Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'map.s' not found

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem; is this what you're trying to do?

```r
setwd("~/College/2021-2022/Fall 2021/Programming for Biologists BIOM 419/R Project 1/")

library(MASS)
data(mammals)
plot(mammals$body, mammals$brain, col="RED", pch=15, cex=1,
     xlab="Body Weight", ylab="Brain Weight", 
     main="Plot of Brain Wt. as a Function of Body Wt.")
```

[image]

```r
mammals1<-mammals[order(mammals$body),]
mammals1$logbody<-log(mammals1$body)
mammals1$logbrain<-log(mammals1$brain)
plot(mammals1$logbody, mammals1$logbrain, col="RED", pch=15, cex=1,
     xlab="log Body Weight", ylab=" log Brain Weight", 
     main="Plot of Brain Wt. as a Function of Body Wt.")
```

[image]

```r
Tick_data <- read.csv("data/Tick_2017_map.csv")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I added the errors I am getting from rstudio to my post.

Comment: Try `Tick_data <- read.csv("data/Tick_2017_map.csv")` - do you get the same error?

Comment: You're welcome. I can also recommend the [here package](http://jenrichmond.rbind.io/post/how-to-use-the-here-package/) to avoid these types of situations in future.